# Error when running deepdream on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: python, ubuntu, anaconda

When I run [deep dream](https://github.com/google/deepdream) on Ubuntu 14.04 I am presented with this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dream.py", line 7, in <module>
from google.protobuf import text_format
ImportError: No module named google.protobuf
```

When I run `python --version` I get this:

`Python 2.7.10 :: Anaconda 2.3.0 (64-bit)`

I have made sure to follow the install instructions and have installed all the dependencies. I am not sure why I am getting this error but any help is appreciated.

Comment: How did you install the dependencies? Are you sure you installed it for the correct Python version? Because it looks like you don't have protocol buffers installed.

Comment: I downloaded protobuf from the repository on github and did a `make` and `make check` and `make install` after running the autogen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`protobuf` is used to add a single line into `deploy.prototxt` file.
You can just add the line:
`force_backward: true` to `deploy.prototxt` and remove that dependency.

You will have to change your code from:

```
model = caffe.io.caffe_pb2.NetParameter()
text_format.Merge(open(net_fn).read(), model)
model.force_backward = True
open('tmp.prototxt', 'w').write(str(model))

net = caffe.Classifier('tmp.prototxt', param_fn,
                       mean = np.float32([104.0, 116.0, 122.0]), # ImageNet mean, training set dependent
                       channel_swap = (2,1,0)) # the reference model has channels in BGR order instead of RGB
```

to:

```
net = caffe.Classifier(net_fn, param_fn,
                       mean = np.float32([104.0, 116.0, 122.0]), # ImageNet mean, training set dependent
                       channel_swap = (2,1,0)) # the reference model has channels in BGR order instead of RGB
```

and remove line

```
from google.protobuf import text_format
```

---

If you just want to try out deepdream have a look at [deepdreamer](https://github.com/kesara/deepdreamer)